# Select specific value from a column in SQL

Tags: sql

I am new to sql and I would like to select specific value form a column, count them and group them by another value; the code I am using is :

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT event_name), client_package_id
    
FROM userevent
WHERE event_happened_at >= from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-10-19T11:44:24Z')
GROUP BY client_package_id
```

I am expecting 3 columns, one  "client_package_id" other "event_name" which is grouped by specific values in the column and the other one is the quantity of column 2.

Here is the example :

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data, current and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: I'm not sure about other DB systems, but in mysql you can use `GROUP_CONCAT(fieldname)` (if I understood your question correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading it correctly, you need to also group by event_name, and include it in the SELECT.
eg

```
SELECT client_package_id, event_name, COUNT (*)
    
FROM userevent
WHERE event_happened_at >= from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-10-19T11:44:24Z')
GROUP BY client_package_id, event_name
```

If that doesn't return what you're after, please provide more details - ie sample data and expected result.

Comment: I just uploaded a pic representing my expectation

Comment: @farbodalidaei I don't understand how you get those results from that data in your picture. Eg there is no C First in the initial table, but 1 in the results... while there is a C Third in the table but your results show 0.

Comment: That was typo and your script i working, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

SELECT client_package_id, event_name, COUNT (event_name)
FROM userevent
WHERE event_happened_at >= from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-10-19T11:44:24Z')
GROUP BY client_package_id, event_name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT client_package_id, event_name, COUNT(event_name) as 'event_quantity'
FROM userevent
WHERE event_happened_at >= from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-10-19T11:44:24Z')
GROUP BY client_package_id, event_name
```